# Maven Classpath Log4J NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, jar, log4j, classpath

Hi I am trying to create a JAR which has multiple Main classes that I can run.
I am building with Maven and my pom.xml looks like this:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    ch.uzh.ifi.ce
    CombinatorialAuction
    1.0
    Combinatorial Auction

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>
        jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
    </sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.host.url>
        http://localhost:9000
    </sonar.host.url>
</properties>

<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I then try to run a Main class using the following command

```
java -cp CombinatorialAuction-1.0.jar ch.uzh.ifi.ce.cca.bneexecution.SingleBNERunner
```

However I get the following exception, which indicates that the dependencies do not seem to work.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pom.xml lacks a dependency on SLF4J API:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

A bit strange that `slf4j-log4j12` does not bring that dependency, though.

Comment: Nope that didn't help

Comment: Anyway, those Log4J 2 JARs are of no use to `slf4j-log4j12`, as it makes use of `log4j:log4j` artifacts (Log4J 1.2). You can try including Log4J 1.2 instead of Log4J 2.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.
The problem was that the dependencies weren't packaged with the jar ... (Stupid of me). I used the shade plugin to create a jar with the dependencies.